# Spartacus Angular 9 api calling multiple times even using shareReplay()

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular9, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to avoid duplicate API calls in custom cart service but somehow it's calling the API method multiple times. Below is my code sample:

parent component:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <app-list-item [list]="item"></app-list-item>
</div>
```

Applistitem.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  $data = this.api.getActivedata();
}
```

api.service.ts

```
public getActiveCartData(): Observable<Cart> {
   
  this.activeCart$ = this.activeCartService.getActiveCartId().pipe(
    map((cart: any) => cart),
      switchMap((cartId) => this.getCartData(cartId)),
    );
    
  return this.activeCart$;
}
    
private getData(cartId) {
  
  return this.http
    .get<Occ.CART>(
      this.occEndpoints.getUrl('cart', {
        userId: this.userId,
        cartId: this.cartId,
      })
    ).pipe(this.converterService.pipeable(CART_NORMALIZER),shareReplay());
  
}
```

I tried with share replay also still getactivedata method call multiple times. Did I do anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try and find out if this.activeCartService.getActiveCartId() emits multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use it in the wrong place.
Please check the official implementation:

```
this.activeCart$ = //...
  //...
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
);
```

Consider using this stream as service property instead of the getter method. Otherwise, you create a new stream every time, probably that's where your problem comes from. Additionally, recommend using `distinctUntilChanged` and parameters for shareReplay.